# What’s the equivalent of rsplit() with re.split()?

Tags: python, regex

[`rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) starts splitting at the end of the string. How can I start splitting at the end of the string when using [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split)?

Example:

```
import re
splitme = "a!b?c!d"
re.split(r"[!\?]", splitme, maxsplit = 1)
```

Returns:

```
a
```

But I want:

```
d
```

While I was writing this question, I realized I could use

```
re.split(r"[!\?]", splitme)[-1]
```

But that doesn’t seem like the most effective way since this splits the entire string, while we could stop after the first match (from the right).

Comment: well, you *could* reverse the string, but I don't see how it would be more efficient than your solution. You can try to `timeit` both approaches and see which one performs better for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to split if you just want the last one.

```
match = re.search(r'[^!?]*$', splitme)
if match:
    return match.group(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) contains no `rsplit` method. Thus, you need to write your own method or function.

Here is an example:

```py
import re

def re_rsplit(pattern, text, maxsplit):
    if maxsplit < 1 or not pattern.search(text): # If split is 0 or less, or upon no match
        return [text]                            # Return the string itself as a one-item list
    prev = len(text)                             # Previous match value start position
    cnt = 0                                      # A match counter
    result = []                                  # Output list
    for m in reversed(list(pattern.finditer(text))):
        result.append(text[m.end():prev])        # Append a match to resulting list
        prev = m.start()                         # Set previous match start position
        cnt += 1                                 # Increment counter
        if cnt == maxsplit:                      # Break out of for loop if...
            break                                # ...match count equals max split value
    result.append(text[:prev])                   # Append the text chunk from start
    return reversed(result)                      # Return reversed list
```

See a demo test:

```py
splitme = "a!b?c!d"
pattern = re.compile(r'[!?]')
print(list(re_rsplit(pattern, splitme, -1))) # => ['a!b?c!d']
print(list(re_rsplit(pattern, splitme, 0)))  # => ['a!b?c!d']
print(list(re_rsplit(pattern, splitme, 1)))  # => ['a!b?c', 'd']
print(list(re_rsplit(pattern, splitme, 2)))  # => ['a!b', 'c', 'd']
print(list(re_rsplit(pattern, splitme, 3)))  # => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
print(list(re_rsplit(pattern, splitme, 50))) # => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/JRJKu7).

You might want to split into as many chunks as possible if `maxsplit` is set to a negative value. Then, use

````py
def re_rsplit(pattern, text, maxsplit):
    if maxsplit == 0 or not pattern.search(text): # If split is 0 or less, or upon no match
        return [text]                            # Return the string itself as a one-item list
    prev = len(text)                             # Previous match value start position
    cnt = 0                                      # A match counter
    result = []                                  # Output list
    for m in reversed(list(pattern.finditer(text))):
        result.append(text[m.end():prev])        # Append a match to resulting list
        prev = m.start()                         # Set previous match start position
        cnt += 1                                 # Increment counter
        if maxsplit > 0 and cnt >= maxsplit:     # Break out of for loop if maxsplit is greater than 0 and...
            break                                # ...match count is more or equals max split value
    result.append(text[:prev])                   # Append the text chunk from start
    return reversed(result)                      # Return reversed list```
````

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/pSfDyk). Then,

```py
print(list(re_rsplit(pattern, splitme, -1))) # => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], NOT ['a!b?c!d']
```