# Find first match in string from the end

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```
Manager of Medical Threat Devlop at Micro
```

I want to find any words that go after `at`, `for`, `of`. Here, I want to get the `['Micro']` (that is at the end of string, after the last `at` word).

**Current code**

If I apply `r'(?:for|at|of)\s+(.*)'` I will get incorrect `['Medical Threat Devlop at Micro']`.

**More examples**:

- `Manager of Medical Threat Devlop at Canno` -> `Canno`
- `Manager of Medicalof Threat Devlop of Canno` -> `Canno`
- `Manager of Medicalfor Threat Devlop for Canno` -> `Canno`
- `Threat Devlop at Canno Matt` -> `Canno Matt`

Comment: CAn you show some more input and output?

Comment: What if the string is `Threat Devlop at Canno Matt`? What output do you expect.

Comment: @SharimIqbal `Canno Matt`

Comment: Then you could use my answer.

Comment: @SharimIqbal i need findall ,because it will be ported to another languages, split it's not real reg.exp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What’s the equivalent of rsplit() with re.split()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953278/what-s-the-equivalent-of-rsplit-with-re-split)

Comment: Can I use `re.finditer`?

Comment: @SharimIqbal  I java i had            `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexString);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(slug);

            while (matcher.find()) {
                result.add(matcher.group(1));`

Comment: Why are you asking a python question if you want to implement this in java? Why not ask a java question in the first place?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi because solution which was proposed was not fair regexp, it's just a hack not to make regular expression. Regular expression mostly should walk in any language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r'.*\b(?:for|at|of)\s+(.*)', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XcuCJv/2). *Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:for|at|of)` - `for`, `at` or `of`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(.*)`  - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

Another regex that will fetch the same results is

```py
re.findall(r'\b(?:for|at|of)\s+((?:(?!\b(?:for|at|of)\b).)*)$', text)
```

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:for|at|of)` - `for`, `at` or `of`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `((?:(?!\b(?:for|at|of)\b).)*)` - Group 1: any char, other than a line break char, zero or more but as many as possible, occurrences, that does not start a `for`, `at` or `of` as a whole word char sequence
- `$` - end of string.

Note you can also use `re.search` since you expect a single match:

```py
match = re.search(r'.*\b(?:for|at|of)\s+(.*)', text)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `re.split` would work this.

**Your question is not fully clear give some more input and output examples.**

```
import re
s = 'Manager of Medical Threat Devlop at Micro'
s = re.split(r'at |for |of ',s)[-1:]
print(s)
```

###### OUTPUT

```
                 IN                         :  OUTPUT
'Manager of Medical Threat Devlop at Micro' : ['Micro']
'Threat Devlop at Canno Matt'               : ['Canno Matt']
```

THERE IS ANOTHER METHOD TO DO THIS (USING `re.finditer`).

```py
import re
string = 'Threat Devlop at Canno Matt'
s = re.finditer(r'(at | for | of )',string,)
last_index = list(s)[-1].end()
print(string[last_index:])
```

I am not good in `re` at all.(But I get it)

---

Yeah there is another to do this.(Using `re.findall`)

```py
import re
string = 'Threat Devlop at Canno of Matjkasa'
s = re.findall(r'.*(?:at|for|of)\s+', string)

print(string.replace(*s,''))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with a regex, then here's the way to do it.

Replace matches of the following regex with the empty string:

```
.*\b(?:for|at|of)\b\s?
```

This will match:

- `.*`: any character (by its nature, this pattern will match as most characters as possible)
- `\b(?:for|at|of)\b`: your hotwords between boundary symbols
- `\s?`: an optional space

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/hSbYaI/1)

Comment: Easy as using `re.sub`.

Comment: @lemon I need it by findall

Comment: It doesn't make sense to force an operator, but this answer will return more accurate results with respect to a finding operation using a `split` function.

Comment: @lemon i have a list of other regexp(6) ,and remaking all code to sub, it will be more harder, rather create one correctly